# Real exponential field with restricted analytic functions: $\mathbb R_{an,\exp,\log}$ has quantifier elimination, but $\mathbb R_{an,\exp}$ does not.

Tags: logic, model-theory

At a talk sometime ago a result was presented, which I believe originates from:

> *van den Dries, Lou; Miller, Chris*, [**On the real exponential field with restricted analytic functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02758635), Isr. J. Math. 85, No. 1-3, 19-56 (1994). [ZBL0823.03017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0823.03017).

At some point it was mentioned that $\mathbb R_{an,\exp,\log}$ admits quantifier elimination while $\mathbb R_{an,\exp}$ does not. Here $\mathbb R_{an,\exp}$ is the theory of the (ordered) real exponential field with function symbols for all restricted analytic functions. Then of course $\mathbb R_{an,\exp,\log}$ is just adding a function symbol for logarithms.

Someone in the audience remarked that $\log(x)$ (or more precisely, its graph) is quantifier-free definable by $x = \exp(y)$. Then a fairly simple formula was presented to show why you really need $\log$ as a function symbol for quantifier elimination, and there is my question: I just cannot remember or reconstruct that formula. So what would be a simple example of some formula in this setting that is not equivalent to a quantifier-free formula in $\mathbb R_{an,\exp}$?

I am probably missing something obvious here, but now it's haunting me.

Comment: How do you add a function symbol for $ \log $ when it's not defined everywhere ?

Comment: You just make it 0 everywhere else (same thing happens for the analytic function symbols, they are really only defined on some bounded interval). Unfortunately, $\exists y (exp(y) = x)$ is just equivalent to $0 < x$.

Comment: Ok for $ \log $ . Yes, I deleted that bit because I realized it was the *ordered* field. Perhaps something like $ \log (x) \log (y) \geq 1 $ ? (I'll stop guessing after that )

Comment: You mentioned grading based on presentation once. I will deduct 2 points from your grade for not using `\exp` and `\log`.

Comment: @Asaf haha, point(s) taken.

Comment: @Max that may actually work. At least, I can't come up with a quantifier-free equivalent formula.

Comment: @MarkKamsma : yes, that's how I did my guess work too : anything with only additions of log's can be converted by exponentiating, so I just put some multiplication; and then I put $1$ instead of $0$ because if it were $0$ you could convert it to "both are nonnegative or both are nonpositive". But I don't have a proof that it has no quantifier-free equivalent, and it's been a while since I dealt with these so I don't really know how to approach it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By pure coincidence I happened to come across an answer to this question while browsing [David Marker's homepage](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/). In his note *A failure of quantifier elimination* (with A. Macintyre), he answers exactly this question for different languages (see his homepage for a download of that file).

The short answer is that
$$
\exists z (\exp(\exp(z)) = x \land y = z \exp(z))
$$
is not equivalent to a quantifier-free formula. So this is somewhat similar to one of the formulas suggested in the comments. This is even in a bigger language, but then it certainly works for my question. Just a sanity check, if we allow $\log(x)$ in our language, then this formula is equivalent to
$$
x > 1 \land y = \log(x) \log(\log(x)).
$$

Some more examples are mentioned in that note. It also contains a proof of why the above mentioned formula is not equivalent to a quantifier-free formula. This proof is not trivial at all, so I will not repeat it here.